# Why (and how) did using cat on binary files mess up the terminal?

Tags: terminal, cat, binary

If I understand the `cat` manual correctly:

> concatenate files and print on the standard output

`cat` will take files as argument and print them on standard output.
What I don't get is if I use the command:

```
cat img.png > copy.png
```

I will obtain 2 png files identical while if I just

```
cat img.png
```

I have all chance that my terminal get messed up and misinterpret what I type.

- How's that possible?
- Binary values are still binary data. Why it does not simply shows a series of 0 and 1 or the interpretation of those binary data in ASCII or whatever the encoding in terminal is?
- Is this behavior also possible by `cat`ing a text file containing strange characters?
- Should a mechanism to prevent this behavior  like try{}catch{} statement should be implemented?

Comment: Your terminal does not get messed up. It is in a state you forced it into by sending it control characters. That you cannot use it any more after changing the state might not be what you wanted, but it is entirely a result of you not understanding the consequences of your actions. That would be the same as switching your font color to green in a word processor and saying your word processor is messed up, only because **you** don't know how to switch it back to black font without e.g. exiting the program.

Comment: a `reset` command might help sometimes, but this is no miracle solution.

Comment: The actual sequence to type is Control-J reset Control-J. Almost always restores sanity.

Comment: @Joshua And what's the difference between a lone `reset` and a `reset` between Ctrl-J keypresses? I can't see any (nor any reason to go the more complicated way)

Comment: Because if the terminal was left in RAW mode, Enter generates Ctrl-M instead of Ctrl-J so the shell doesn't see the necessary keystroke to end a line and run the command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cat` concatenates file(s) given as argument(s) on the command line
and prints the concatenated output to the standard output. 
It reads bytes (conceptually, one-at-a-time)
and, by default, does not perform any interpretation of the bytes it reads.

In your first example, you are redirecting stdout to a file, which is why you get a new file.

In your second example, the bytes are written to the terminal, and it is *the terminal* that is interpreting sequences of characters as control sequences for the terminal. This is why you get unusual behaviour on your terminal. 
It has nothing to do with `cat` *per se*. 
`cat` doesn't know what you are going to do with its output. You might be sending it through a pipe to another program to interpret/process/print it or which passes it to an audio driver to play "Singing in the Rain".

So, following the Unix philosophy:

> do one thing, do one thing only, but do it well

`cat` should not attempt to second-guess or interpret what you are trying to do.

---

From [@Kiwy's comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-and-how-did-using-cat-on-binary-files-mess-up-the-terminal/119485#comment187518_119485) (fixed for grammar):

> does this mean that if you `cat` a binary file which contains in plain-text instructions like `rm -rf`, this could be interpreted?

Yes and no. Let me explain:

No: if you `cat` to a terminal, because it (the terminal software)
is sending the output to your screen, or interpreting control sequences
(it is emulating an old piece of hardware, e.g., *a teletype device*).

*but*:

Yes: if you `cat` to a pipe and the program receiving can interpret the characters as commands.

Look at this for example:

```bash
cat anyOldShellScript | bash
```

In this example, `bash` will interpret what it gets as commands, and therefore run the characters `rm -rf` if they exist in that content passed to the pipe by `cat`.

Comment: does it means that if you `cat` a binary files that may contains in plain text instruction like `rm -rf .` this could be interpreted ?

Comment: @Kiwy control characters don't exist on your keyboard, but you can make `echo` output them if you choose. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux for how to do it and http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm for some of what is possible

Comment: @DavidWilkins hey thanks that's nice, so much things to learn and no time for that :-(

Answer (score 4):

I guess this happens mostly because of non-printable characters with codes below 0x20. Those are special control/escape codes, which are used for keys like Backspace, Delete etc.