# Jumbled interface due to reading binary files in screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using bash and screen and catted `/dev/sda1`. This potentially outputted escape codes that changed screen's state. The closest question I found is [Why using cat on binary files messed up the terminal and how?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how)

I tried using `reset` and `stty sane`, but these do not appear to affect screen. They only affect the bash sessions inside. How can I reset or restore sanity to screen?

Here is how it looks

[image: Messed up terminal]

Comment: What awful terminal client could be doing something like that?

Comment: I'm using gnome-terminal with screen and bash, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, so `screen` must probably need to be restarted.  I don't use that, tried it a few times and got too many problems with it.

Comment: Well I've tried reconnecting, but restarting my screen would mean that I lose my vim session and other jobs in those terminals. Are you suggesting another multiplexer where this issue is easily resolved?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for `screen` to be confused.  You can *detach* your session, run [`reset`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) outside `screen`, re-attach to the session and run `reset` within `screen`.  With any `reset`, the terminal (or window) would be cleared, but at least you should be able to resume whatever is running in the window(s).

Besides `reset`, I find these useful (they do not make a full reset):

- [`tput cnorm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) (make the cursor visible)
- `tput enacs` (repairs line-drawing)

Your terminal may also have a *reset* feature, but that would be limited to setting the terminal's modes (such as line-drawing), and have little effect on resetting the I/O modes (such as newline-conversion), which can be a nuisance.  When using `reset`, you may have to type

`reset`<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

to get the terminal's attention — both within and outside `screen`.

Comment: This solved the problem:
Detach, reset, go back, c-a a to get a terminal, c-a Z to reset.

Comment: Well only until I c-a a'd, then the problem came right back.

Answer (score 1):

Try C-a Z (GNU Screen 'reset')

Comment: This does not work, after doing this I have [image](http://puu.sh/oLFPf/c92b267b77.png)