# Why running `cat /etc/localtime` on PuTTY puts a stream of "PuTTY" in the prompt?

Tags: cat, xterm, putty

I was randomly experimenting and I found that running `cat /etc/localtime` on PuTTY and on xterm have different effects.

Example:

```
root@webtest:~# cat /etc/localtime
TZif2

     ▒
      ▒▒Kmp▒▒ǀ▒▒▒p▒Ƀprp▒▒▒▒_Tp▒▒▒p▒A▒p▒nop▒#
▒O▒▒▒p▒▒▒ɧ▒#▒Op▒▒▒k▒p"p▒r▒p▒Pp▒2Lp▒▒p▒▒▒p▒▒p▒ȷ▒_p▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xl▒▒h]▒▒XN▒▒?p▒80▒▒:▒▒▒X▒p▒▒▒p▒/p▒▒ p▒▒b▒˵R▒▒▒▒̀K▒▒ܢ▒͕4▒▒▒K`▒r▒▒▒ſp▒u▒Ϭg▒▒R▒▒Х▒p▒T▒▒ьI▒▒2f▒҅▒p▒Y▒▒▒I▒▒▒9▒ ▒)▒ ▒▒ ▒      PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY▒ ▒▒ ▒▒ ܹY ݲ▒▒ޢu▒ߒf▒▒W▒▒rH▒▒b9▒▒R*▒▒B▒2
▒▒!▒▒
      ▒▒
         ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒   ▒z▒ ▒j▒ ▒c▒▒▒S▒▒▒C▒▒▒3▒▒▒#s▒▒d▒▒U▒▒▒F▒
▒*
▒7▒t(▒d▒T▒C▒3▒#▒ܐ͐▒㽠Ӡ▒Ñ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|▒ lr!\c"LT#<E$,6%'&
'C▒'▒4▒(▒%▒)▒▒*▒▒+▒▒,▒▒-▒ڐ.▒ː/t▒▒0d▒▒1]▒2r▒3=▒4R▒5▒62x68▒8▒a9▒v▒:▒C;▒X▒<▒_▒=▒:▒>▒A▒?▒▒@f#▒A▒9BF▒Cd
                  %▒EC▒FɐG#▒G▒▒I▒I▒▒J▒K▒▒L̿▒M▒▒N▒▒▒OnnP▒▒▒QW▒▒Rle▒S7l▒TLG▒UN▒V,)▒V▒0▒XFX▒▒Y▒(Z▒▒[▒
\▒]▒▒▒_▒▒`_▒a}▒b?▒c]̐d▒e=▒▒▒▒g▒▒g藐h▒r▒i▒y▒j▒T▒k▒[▒l▒qm▒=▒n▒Soh▒p▒5qQ<rfs1tE▒uv/▒v▒▒x▒x▒▒y▒ِz▒▒{λ▒|▒�}▒▒▒~y▒▒     PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY









































 ▒▒c    LMTWESTWETWEMTCETCESTTZif2

                                  ▒
                                   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒Kmp▒▒▒▒▒▒ǀ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒Ƀp▒▒▒▒rp▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒_Tp▒▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒A▒p▒▒▒▒▒nop▒▒▒▒▒#
▒▒▒▒▒▒O▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ɧ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒#▒▒▒▒▒▒▒Op▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒k▒▒▒▒▒▒p"p▒▒▒▒▒r▒p▒▒▒▒▒Pp▒▒▒▒▒2Lp▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒ȷ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒_p▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒xl▒▒▒▒▒▒h]▒▒▒▒▒▒XN▒▒▒▒▒▒?p▒▒▒▒▒80▒▒▒▒▒▒:▒▒▒▒▒▒▒X▒p▒▒▒▒▒▒▒p▒▒▒▒▒/p▒▒▒▒▒▒ p▒▒▒▒▒▒b▒▒▒▒▒˵R▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒̀K▒▒▒▒▒▒ܢ▒▒▒▒▒͕4▒▒▒▒▒▒▒K`▒▒▒▒▒r▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ſp▒▒▒▒▒u▒▒▒▒▒Ϭg▒▒▒▒▒▒R▒▒▒▒▒▒Х▒p▒▒▒▒▒T▒▒▒▒▒▒ьI▒▒▒▒▒▒2f▒▒▒▒▒҅▒p▒▒▒▒▒Y▒▒▒▒▒▒▒I▒▒▒▒▒▒▒9▒ ▒▒▒▒▒)▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒   ▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ܹY ▒▒▒▒ݲ▒▒▒▒▒▒ޢu▒▒▒▒▒ߒf▒▒▒▒▒▒W▒▒▒▒▒▒rH▒▒▒▒▒▒b9▒▒▒▒▒▒R*▒▒▒▒▒▒B▒▒▒▒▒2
▒▒▒▒▒▒!▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
                  ▒▒▒▒▒▒
                         ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒z▒ ▒▒▒▒▒j▒ ▒▒▒▒▒c▒▒▒▒▒▒▒S▒▒▒▒▒▒▒C▒▒▒▒▒▒▒3▒▒▒▒▒▒▒#s▒▒▒▒▒▒d▒▒▒▒▒▒U▒▒▒▒▒▒▒F▒
▒*
▒7▒t(▒d▒T▒C▒3▒#▒ܐ͐▒㽠Ӡ▒Ñ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒|▒ lr!\c"LT#<E$,6%'&
'C▒'▒4▒(▒%▒)▒▒*▒▒+▒▒,▒▒-▒ڐ.▒ː/t▒▒0d▒▒1]▒2r▒3=▒4R▒5▒62x68▒8▒a9▒v▒:▒C;▒X▒<▒_▒=▒:▒>▒A▒?▒▒@f#▒A▒9BF▒Cd
                  %▒EC▒FɐG#▒G▒▒I▒I▒▒J▒K▒▒L̿▒M▒▒N▒▒▒OnnP▒▒▒QW▒▒Rle▒S7l▒TLG▒UN▒V,)▒V▒0▒XFX▒▒Y▒(Z▒▒[▒
\▒]▒▒▒_▒▒`_▒a}▒b?▒c]̐d▒e=▒▒▒▒g▒▒g藐h▒r▒i▒y▒j▒T▒k▒[▒l▒qm▒=▒n▒Soh▒p▒5qQ<rfs1tE▒uv/▒v▒▒x▒x▒▒y▒ِz▒▒{λ▒|▒�}▒▒▒~y▒▒









































 ▒▒c    LMTWESTWETWEMTCETCEST
WET0WEST,M3.5.0/1,M10.5.0
PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYroot@webtest:~# PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY
```

But when I run on xterm, it gives me this:

```
root@webtest:~# cat /etc/localtime
TZif2

     Ý
      æmpÇíppêp¢AÙp£nop¤#
                         ð¥O¢ðªïpªôð­É§ð®§#ð¯ Op°ð±kð²p"p³rp´Pp·2Lp¸Èp¸ÿ¹p¹ïªp¼È·ð½¸¨ð¾ðÀððÁxlðÂh]ðÃXNðÄ?pÅ80ðÆ:ðÇX¬pÇÙßpÉ/pÉñ pÊâbðËµRðËì£àÌKàÌÜ¢ðÍ4ðÍÃK`Îr¢àÎÅ¿pÏuðÏ¬gàÐR
           àÐ¥¡pÑTøðÑIàÒ2fàÒ
pÓYÄðÔIµðÕ9Ñ Ö)Â ×³ Ø^[[?64;1;2;6;6;9;15;18;21;22c      ¤ Øù Ùé Ü¹Y Ý²
                                                                       Þ¢u ßf àW árH âb9 ãR* äB2
                 æ!ý ç
                       èû
                          éêü êÚí ëÊÞ ìºÏ íªÀ î± ï¢ ðz ñj
                                                          òc¯ óS  ôC õ3 ö#s ÷d øU øóF 
      «*

7t(dT3úã½ Ó Ã½¬® lr!\c"LT#<E$,6%'&
                                  'CÚ
                                     Ë5A
                                        9BF
                                           %çN¬¡leÎ`_Õa}êe=®=5qQ<rfs1tEùuv/Âæÿÿÿ
```

Why is PuTTY putting `PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY` on the prompt?

---

**Edit**: This question isn't a duplicate of [Why using cat on binary files messed up the terminal and how?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how)

The linked question asks why the ouput is different, even when redirecting the output to a file.

My question is asking why it is showing `PuTTY` in the prompt (note: *on the prompt*, where we type the commands), on PuTTY.

I'm really sorry, but I'm not being able to express my doubt any better.

Comment: It's not a duplicate (of the given question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an FAQ ([for PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty)):

> **A.7.12 When I cat a binary file, I get ‘PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY’ on my command line.**
>
> Don't do that, then.
>
> This is designed behaviour; when PuTTY receives the character Control-E from the remote server, it interprets it as a request to identify itself, and so it sends back the string ‘PuTTY’ as if that string had been entered at the keyboard. Control-E should only be sent by programs that are prepared to deal with the response. Writing a binary file to your terminal is likely to output many Control-E characters, and cause this behaviour. Don't do it. It's a bad plan.
>
> To mitigate the effects, you could configure the answerback string to be empty (see section 4.3.7); but writing binary files to your terminal is likely to cause various other unpleasant behaviour, so this is only a small remedy.

PuTTY's developers started off by copying things, and sometimes they forget the reason.  The answerback sequence (for a while) in xterm would echo "xterm".  [But that went away in 1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_101):

> change default answerback response to an empty string.

Notwithstanding that, you'll still find people saying that xterm does this (by default).

When a terminal sends an answerback response, the result is just as if you had ***typed*** that information.  Your shell (or other program) will echo the characters.

Comment: This answers 90% of the question. But still: Why does it go to the prompt? After running the command and hitting Enter, it will run `PuTTYPuTTY[...]`. Is there any key sequence that makes it go to the prompt?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/localtime` is a symbolic link to a binary file, not a text file.  Dumping the contents of a binary file to a terminal can have interesting and unexpected results, particularly if some of the binary data happen to match terminal control codes.  PuTTY may have a control code to output its name, which xterm does not or if it does, it parses differently.