# Commands to read the content of .journal file?

Tags: journalctl

Well, the answer is simple - using command "journalctl".

But let me describe the problem first,

I encountered an ubuntu server crash event and some log/.journal files were extracted successfully, and the next way to deal with this event is to read/analyze these files.

There were 2 requests being discussed:

A. How to read the .journal files under Windows environment

B. other way to read the .journal files than using Windows OS

The first one is the most important request but I skipped it because it seemed too difficult and using another ubuntu host with command "journalctl --file /path_to_the_file" can solve the goal perfectly.(and also export the content to .txt file via ">" symbol)

Now I discovered that when and after using command "cat" to read .journal file, gibberish will appear on the console display and I have no choice but to reboot to clear out the mess.

Command "vi" doesn't work either.

So, is command "journalctl" the only and direct way to browse the .journal file normally?

Comment: It's not a text file format. Specification of the on-disk format can be found at https://systemd.io/JOURNAL_FILE_FORMAT/. You can write your own  parser for it or use `journalctl`. There are bindings for most programming languages. See for instance https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Systemd::Journal::Read for perl

Comment: Yes...............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I discovered that when and after using command "cat" to read .journal file, gibberish will appear on the console display

Indeed. It's a binary file

> and I have no choice but to reboot to clear out the mess.

This is not correct. You can usually fix this by using the `Control-j, reset, Control-j` combination (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-and-how-did-using-cat-on-binary-files-mess-up-the-terminal) for more details about the "messed up terminal" in these situations), or just open a new terminal.

> So, is command "journalctl" the only and direct way to browse the .journal file normally?

As it is a binary file, the only choice is to use a program that can parse that binary format. This is what journalctl does out of the box. Alternatively, you could use a custom script: in Python, for example, you can use the systemd.journal library (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331116/reading-systemd-journal-from-python-script), although I'm not sure it is portable to Windows.

You could also choose a different approach: copy the files somewhere (a virtual machine, even a Linux container is probably enough) and then  run `journalctl -D <path to exported journal>`.